# Как передать переменные окружения из docker-compose.yml в Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

```
Структура папок следующая:
/
  /account
    Dockerfile
  docker-compose.yml
  .env
```

Файл env:

```
TEST=test
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  account:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: account/src
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ONE: ${TEST}
        TWO: $TEST
        THREE: 3
    environment:
      - FOUR=${TEST}
      - FIVE=$TEST
      - SIX=6
    command: some command
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.19.0-alpine3.11
WORKDIR /app
RUN echo ONE $ONE
RUN echo TWO $TWO
RUN echo THREE $THREE
RUN echo FOUR $FOUR
RUN echo FIVE $FIVE
RUN echo SIX $SIX

.. whatever

EXPOSE $APP_PORT
CMD ["some", "command"]
```

В терминал вижу:

```
Step 3/19 : RUN echo ONE $ONE
 ---> Running in caa4cd247d5d
ONE
Removing intermediate container caa4cd247d5d
 ---> 35470ab440be
Step 4/19 : RUN echo TWO $TWO
 ---> Running in 23ac6fd171b7
TWO
Removing intermediate container 23ac6fd171b7
 ---> e45af7802515
Step 5/19 : RUN echo THREE $THREE
 ---> Running in 562ad0182074
THREE
Removing intermediate container 562ad0182074
 ---> f2e8cbe870d0
Step 6/19 : RUN echo FOUR $FOUR
 ---> Running in 9e3217e4731b
FOUR
Removing intermediate container 9e3217e4731b
 ---> d138ea278878
Step 7/19 : RUN echo FIVE $FIVE
 ---> Running in aa1be66d515c
FIVE
Removing intermediate container aa1be66d515c
 ---> 1bb0b844cd41
Step 8/19 : RUN echo SIX $SIX
 ---> Running in 53551d8861b0
SIX
```

При этом само приложение видит переменные окружения (и не видит аргументы).

Как мне передать переменные окружения в Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dockerfile:

```
...
ARG ONE
ENV ONE $ONE
RUN echo $ONE
...
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! я чуть лоб об клавиатуру не разбил

Comment: @muturgan это нормальное явление)))

Comment: А можно запустить компос с указанием переменных окружения, а их указать в компосе?